# 4 dimensional matrix in Armadillo

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

I started using Armadillo relatively recently, and although I like it a lot, it would be useful if it had ways of storing 4D matrices.  Is there something I'm missing, or a workaround for this?

The last dimension would just have a size of three, so in theory I could have something like:

```
std::vector<arma::cube> 4Dmatrix(3);
for (int index=0; index<3; index++)
  4Dmatrix[index] = cube(size1, size2, size3);
```

However, it feels like there must be a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially use the [`field`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field) class which stores arbitrary objects as elements in a vector, matrix or cube structure. E.g. (from the documentation) to create a `field` containing `vec` vectors:

```
// create a field containing vectors
field<vec> F(3,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in way. If you look at the source, you will see that there are individual implementations for vectors, matrices and cubes.

Maybe a [Boost multi array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) could be of use to you.